# get запрос работает некорректно

Tags: javascript, get

Здравствуйте. По каким причинам не отправляется get запрос ?

```
    echo '<form method="get" id="' . $row["ArticleID"] .'" action="/view/open-news.php" ><div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"> '. $row["ArticleName"] . '<br>Дата: ' . $row["ArticleDate"] . '</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><div>'. $row["ArticleCode"] . '</div><button onclick="openNews(\''.$row["ArticleID"].'\')">Подробнее</button></div>
            <div class="panel-footer">'. 'Автор: ' . $row["Login"] . '</div>
        </div></form>';
```

Так я вывожу формы. Вот js скрипт

```
function openNews(id) {

    var form = document.getElementById(id);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type","hidden");
    input.setAttribute("value",id);
    input.setAttribute("name","news_id");
    form.appendChild(input);
    form.submit();
    form.removeChild(input);

}
```

После submit выполняется get запрос, но параметр news_id не передается. Работает только если вводи вручную по типу `http://platform/view/open-news.php?news_id=1`
параметр news_id не пустой, выводил алертом и в дебаге проверял.

Comment: Если не удалять инпут, то все работает, видимо submit работает асинхронно. И `php` как главный тег тут точно ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вообще обойтись без отдельного скрипта:

```
echo '<form method="get" action="/view/open-news.php" >
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"> '. $row["ArticleName"] . '<br>Дата: ' . $row["ArticleDate"] . '</div>
    <div class="panel-body"><div>'. $row["ArticleCode"] . '</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="' . $row["ArticleID"] .'" name="news_id">
    <button onclick="this.form.submit();">Подробнее</button></div>
    <div class="panel-footer">'. 'Автор: ' . $row["Login"] . '</div>
</div></form>';
```

Comment: я думаю автор хочет спрятать этот кусок от любопытных глаз

Comment: интересно, что именно он хочет спрятать? ))

Comment: вероятно, сейчас за `echo '<a href="/view/open-news.php?news_id=' . $row["ArticleID"] .'">Подробнее</a>'` расстреливают на месте